# Complex LUCENE Query

Tags: lucene

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a LUCENE query like the following:

Field 1, Field 2

---

foo, bar
foo, baz
foo, foo
baz, bar
baz, baz
bar, foo
bar, bar

I want to be able to query and get rows where field 1 = 'foo' OR field 1 = 'baz' and they have equivalent field 2 values.  In this example the records returned would be 
(foo, bar), (foo, baz), (baz, bar), and (baz, baz)

Comment: Could you explain your requirement more thoroughly? I just don't understand what you mean by *equivalent field 2 values* nor can I infer it from your example.

Comment: I apologize for not explaining this well enough.  I want the intersection of the rows where field1 = 'foo' and the rows where field1 = 'baz' based on field2.  So in my example I would get (foo, bar) and (baz, bar) because both contain 'bar' for field2, but I wouldn't get (foo, foo) because there isn't a (baz, foo)